# How can I maximize the value of an RShiny numeric input depending on the value of another input?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, user-input

I have two numeric inputs on my RShiny dashboard. Basically what I would like to do is enforcing that the value of `a` will never raise above the value of `b`. So when specifying `numericInput` of `a`, I would esentially like something like this for the `max` parameter: `max = min(100, input$b)`.

Is it even possible to do it on the UI side? Maybe somehow with ShinyJs? If not, can someone recommend me a workaround in the server function, if any?

I know that in the server function I can access the min and max of the inputs in the form of `input$a[1]` but I don't see how could I limit the user from pushing the numeric input too far up.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  # value of a should always be smaller than b
  numericInput("a", "a:", 5, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
  numericInput("b", "b:", 20, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this `uiOutput / renderUI`. You include a `uiOutput` in the UI and populate it with `renderUI` on the server side. So you have a chance to evaluate `input$b` before rendering `input$a`. You can include `req` in the server to make sure `input$b` has a value before trying to render the UI for `input$b`. This way you can avoid possible errors related to `input$b` not having a value.

**EDIT** 
To 'remember' the value of `a` from before re-creating the numeric input for `a` we can use a `reactiveVal`. Sliders show this better:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  # value of a should always be smaller than b
  # numericInput("a", "a:", 5, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
  uiOutput("aa"),
  sliderInput("b", "b:", 20, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  what_was_a <- reactiveVal()

  output$aa <- renderUI({
    x <- req(input$b)
    sliderInput("a", "a:", what_was_a(), min = 1, max = x, step = 1)
  })

  observe({
    what_was_a(input$a)
  })
}

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: Very useful, thank you very much @teofil ! Only one follow-up question: it is possible to prevent numericInput from always jumping back to its default value defined in its value parameter? Currently, when I modify variable a and b respectively, the moment I modify b, a jumps back to value = mean(c(1,x)).

Comment: Have a look at my edit, is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you very much for your help!